# Why subStr(charArr, 0, strlen(charArr)) and charArr have the same output when using printf but different when passed into a function?

Tags: c

I have a function getCoefnExpo() to get the coefficients and exponents of x in expression a+bx. Expected: a,0,b,1

My subStr() function:

```
char * subStr(char s[], int start, int stop) {
    int c = 0;
    static char sub[100];
    while (start + c < stop) {
        sub[c] = s[start + c];
        c++;
    }
    sub[c] = '\0';
    return sub;
}
char s[] = "01234";
printf("%s\n", subStr(s, 1, 4)); // 123
```

```
void getCoefnExpo(char s[], float container[], int &n) {
    int len = strlen(s);
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char found[100];
        if (i == 0 && s[i] == 'x') {
            container[pos++] = 1;
            if (s[i + 1] != '^') container[pos++] = 1;
            else container[pos++] = (float)(s[i + 2] - '0');
        }
        else if (i == 0 && isdigit(s[i])) {
            for (int j = i; j < len; j++) {
                if (s[j] == 'x') {
                    strncpy_s(found, subStr(s, i, j), 100);
                    container[pos++] = atof(found);
                    if (s[j + 1] != '^') {
                        container[pos++] = 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        container[pos++] = (float)(s[j + 2] - '0');
                    }
                    break;
                }
                else if (s[j] == '+' || s[j] == '-' || j == len - 1) {
                    if (j == len - 1) {
                        strncpy_s(found, subStr(s, i, len), 100);
                    }
                    else {
                        strncpy_s(found, subStr(s, i, j), 100);
                    }
                    container[pos++] = atof(found);
                    container[pos++] = 0;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (s[i] == '+' || s[i] == '-') {
            if (s[i + 1] == 'x' && s[i] == '+') {
                container[pos++] = 1;
                if (s[i + 2] != '^') container[pos++] = 1;
                else container[pos++] = (float)(s[i + 3] - '0');
            }
            else if (s[i + 1] == 'x' && s[i] == '-') {
                container[pos++] = -1;
                if (s[i + 2] != '^') container[pos++] = 1;
                else container[pos++] = (float)(s[i + 3] - '0');
            }
            else {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < len; j++) {
                    if (s[j] == 'x') {
                        strncpy_s(found, subStr(s, i, j), 100);
                        container[pos++] = atof(found);
                        if (s[j + 1] != '^') {
                            container[pos++] = 1;
                        }
                        else {
                            container[pos++] = (float)(s[j + 2] - '0');
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (s[j] == '+' || s[j] == '-' || j == len - 1) {
                        if (j == len - 1) {
                            strncpy_s(found, subStr(s, i, len), 100);
                        }
                        else {
                            strncpy_s(found, subStr(s, i, j), 100);
                        }
                        container[pos++] = atof(found);
                        container[pos++] = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    n = pos;
}
```

The problem:

```
char s1[] = "3+2x";
char *s2 = subStr(s1, 0, strlen(s1)));
printf("|%s|\n", s1);
printf("|%s|\n", s2);
```

The ouput are the same: |3+2x| and strcmp is 0 but when I pass them to getCoefnExpo(char s[]) function:

```
getCoefnExpo(s1); //output 3,0,2,1
getCoefnExpo(s2); //output 3,0
```

I don't think there's anything wrong with the getCoefnExp() as long as I don't use subStr(), the subStr() can't be wrong either cuz they output literally the same results. I have no idea what's going wrong here, please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: C or C++? Decide!

Comment: How do you compile your code? I'm not sure that `char s2[] =...` is valid.

Comment: So do you call `SubStr` from `getCoefnExp`? (The last pargraph suggests so.) If so, keep in mind that `sub` is always the same char buffer, which will be overwritten by subsequent calls to `SubStr`.

Comment: @Zereges C please.

Comment: Could you post the `getCoefnExp` code?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that involves a call to the `getCoefnExp ` function.

Comment: @MOehm You mean having `subStr` inside `getCoefnExp` causes the problem?

Comment: Note that `subStr` returns a static array. So when you call the function a second time the value in the first pointer is overwritten. If you want to use the first function call, you need to copy the string to another variable.

Comment: I do not think the ```char s2[] = subStr(s1, 0, strlen(s1)));``` expression is valid because the size of the array of chars is unknown at compile time.

Comment: @aohKeuqsarraT: That's what I guess. (I haven't looked at `getCoefnExp`.) You use a static buffer, so that you can safely return its address and don't have to worry about memory allocation. That's good, but it comes at a price: Your substrings are ephemeral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are different problems here.

First one is simple: `char s2[] = subStr(s1, 0, strlen(s1)));` is just incorrect C and CLang chokes on it. So I will assume that you only need:

```
char *s2 = subStr(s1, 0, strlen(s1)));
```

Arrays can decay to pointers, and arrays and pointers share the same syntax, but they are still different animals.

The other problem (which is probably to cause of your errors) it that `subStr` returns a static array. An interesting side effect is:

```
char *s1 = subStr("abcd", 0, 2);
char *s2 = subStr("ijkl", 0, 2);

printf("%s-%s\n", s1, s2);   // displays "ij-ij"!
```

Because s1 is just a pointer the the static array from `subStr` and the array has been overwritten by the second call...

So if you use it inside `getCoefnExpo` you should not pass an array that was built from it.

What to remember: static is a possible way to return an array from a function, but the result is just a pointer and the pointed memory will be erased on next call. Caveat emptor...

Answer (score 0):

You have lots of `substr` calls inside `getCoefnExpo` function which overwrites the previous value of `sub` static variable.

Change the `substr` function definition

```
char * subStr(char s[], int start, int stop) {
    int c = 0;
    char sub[100];
    while (start + c < stop) {
        sub[c] = s[start + c];
        c++;
    }
    sub[c] = '\0';
    char *tempRet = strdup(sub);
    return tempRet;
}
```

Also you need to free the memory allocated later stages.

Or

Ask caller to give the buffer

```
char * subStr(char s[], int start, int stop, char *Result)
{
    int c = 0;
    while (start + c < stop) {
        Result[c] = s[start + c];
        c++;
    }
    return Result;
}
```